# AppDomain dependency resolving order

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a .Net multi-appdomain application that resembles a scheduler. Default app domain has a timer and a list of jobs that are contained each in it's own assembly and ran on separate appdomains. Assemblies containing jobs are kept each in it's separate directory under the application root.

```
(root)\Library\AssemblyName\
```

Each assembly directory contains the assembly and its dependencies. Some of those dependencies(e.g. log4net) are contained in the root directory as well because the default domain has it's separate log. I want to load the job assembly and its dependencies from the assembly directory if they exist there, and if not i want to load them from the application root directory. Both main appdomain and child domains use the same library with Interfaces similar to Quartz's IJob interface, so this assembly needs to be loaded from the same file.

The reason for this rather odd requirement is that application jobs should have automatic update ability. So a specially designed class would download the job from an API, unload the appdomain the job is on, delete the job assembly with all the dependencies and reload the appdomain and restart the job, without interfering with the other jobs operation. I've tried using AppdomainSetup to set the Assembly directory before the root directory,

```
domainSetup.PrivateBinPath = @"\\Library\\AssemblyName\\"
```

however my dependencies get resolved from the root directory every time.

So basically i want my dependency to be resolved from the
1. Assembly folder if possible
2. Root directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root *always* takes precedence. There's a few ways around this:

Just make sure the root doesn't actually have any of the references - make your main domain's base directory into another subdirectory rather than the root.

Or, make good use of the `ApplicationBase` in domain setup (that is, *change* the root, rather than the private bin path)

Or, use `PrivateBinPathProbe` to prevent any assembly loading from the root.

Or, set `DisallowApplicationBaseProbing` and implement the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event - this gives you manual control over all assembly resolution in the domain. This is probably the one you *really* want, though I'd combine it with making the base domain just another "module" as well.

Comment: Thanks mate. Your answer has sparked some more questions. First is i use DisallowApplicationBaseProbing do i have to resolve .net dependencies as well? I'm talking about System.Net.Http for example. Do these need to be resolved manually in this case.

Also what is i have 2 different versions of the same dependency, say log4net. And root contains wrong version and AssemblyDirectory has the right one. Will i get an exception or will the framework retry and look further to see that i have the right version in my AssembyDirectory

Comment: @Tusker I don't think you need to manually resolve the assemblies in GAC, which includes System.Net.Http. And as far as I know, the assembly binding algorithms are not backtracking, so unless the DLL is in GAC, it will not try to load a different version - it will simply fail; however, I might be wrong - it should be pretty easy to test :)

Comment: I finally managed it. I've used the second option , and placed all shared dlls in root/Library, adding this path to the application config. All the domains containing separate assemblies have private bin paths set to search (root)\Library\AssemblyName\ first, and (root)\Library\ second thus giving priority to the local instances of dlls over shared ones.